# What is the difference between CommandTimeout and QueryTimeout on the app.config file when using the iSeries Access ODBC Driver?

Tags: .net, odbc, ibm-midrange

I am working with a .NET console application who's iSeries datasource was recently moved. After the move the application experienced timeouts which led me to believe that one of the timeouts needed to be increased (and yes also the network connections optimized).

This is part of the error the console application started generating:

> Error Message: ERROR [HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2
>   for i5/OS]SQL0666 - SQL query exceeds specified time limit or storage
>   limit.

When I increased the `CommandTimeout` in the code from 60 to 120 it worked. However I think it'd be ideal to set the timeout at the connection string so I removed the line.

At the connection string I added `QueryTimeout=120`. When I ran the program, I received the above error once again.

FYI, Here's what my connection string looks like:

```
"Driver=iSeries Access ODBC Driver;System=x.x.x.x;UID=something;pwd=something;QueryTimeout=120"
```

What I noticed doing this is that the data fetch only seemed to not timeout when the `QueryTimeout` was set to zero on the connection string. Setting it to anything else would fail. Meanwhile the `commandTimeout` property in the .net code could be changed as needed and would work. Bringing me to my question, what is the difference between `QueryTimeout` and `CommandTimeout`? And why does `QueryTimeout` only seem to work when it's set to zero but not anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QueryTimeout is a boolean value that indicates whether or not to respect the SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT value which is set through the CommandTimeout property.

### [QueryTimeout](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzatv/rzatvper.htm)

> Specifies whether the driver will disable support for the query timeout attribute, SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT. If disabled, SQL queries will run until they finish.
>   0 = Disable support for the query timeout attribute
>   1 = Allow the query timeout attribute to be set
>   The default is 1.

### [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The time in seconds to wait for the command to execute. The default is 30 seconds.